# JavaScript: Load a script when specific <a> is active

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
function AdImageTag(){ 
var q1=document.getElementById( 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl00_Showcase' ).childNodes[1].innerHTML;
var counter1=0;


function iterate(q1,counter1){

q1= document.getElementById( 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl00_Showcase' ).childNodes[1].innerHTML;

 if(q1.match(/loader.gif/)){      
 counter1=counter1+1;
         setTimeout(function() {iterate(q1,counter1)},100); //100milli seconds

       }else{
function getrakhitagimage(){
    var refrencestring = document.getElementsByClassName('mtb-desc');
    var maindiv = document.getElementsByClassName('bucket');
    for(var i=12;i<maindiv.length;i++){
        var current_bucket = maindiv[i];
alert(current_bucket.firstChild.firstChild.innerHTML);

    }
}

getrakhitagimage();

}
}
iterate(q1,counter1);
}
AdImageTag();
</script>
```

when first time page load my script runs well but on the same page when some other link is clicked and it display content on the same page only but than my script is not running?
so how can i trigger that script when that link is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

## Your question's title & body is different.

### Why script wont run when navigated to the new link?

Your script was loaded & started for that page which had a `<script>` tag with the `src` for your script.

But it may not be so for the new page that is loaded from clicking the link (unless that `<script>` referred to your script with it's `src` attribute).

### Load a script on some event (eg. click)

To load a script when a link is clicked, create a `<script>` element and specify it's `<src>`.

```
<a href="javascript:loadScript()">Click Me</a>
//or
<a href="#" onclick="loadScript();return false;">Click Me</a>
function loadScript(){
  a = document.createElement('script');
  //if it holds functions which needs to be called explicitly
  a.onload=function(){
    functionFromNewScript()
  }
  a.src = "path/to/JSfile";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `<a>` tags load content into the page via AJAX and do not load a completely new page, include a call to `AddImageTag()` in the `<a>` tag's `click` event handler.

(If, on the other hand, they load a completely new page, include the code you have above in the new page.)